# How to get pdf file dimensions in inches

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, mpdf

I am using Laravel, I am getting data from the database in which also include pdf files I want to show every files dimension with each file in a table like in the below image. I have searched a lot about this problem but did not get the correct answer. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Show us some code. It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I have no idea how to do, that's why I did not show the code

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Is this the page size of the pdf? Where are these pdf's stored? Do you want it to be detected automatically? Please provide more information.

Comment: yes, this is pdf file page size height and width. these pdf files are stored in my database I am getting from the database.